# Matplotlib 2D polygon in 3D axes

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, plot

I'm using matplotlib to plot some data as 2D curves in a 3D axes. I use the `ax = axes3d.Axes3D()` to define my axes and `ax.plot(x, y, zs='z')` to plot my 2D curves in the 3D space.

Now I want to add something that looks like what is on this page http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html, but I want to enter directly the coordinates of the vertex.  In this example they have a fixed `z` array and they plot polygons with vertices `(x,y)`, whereas what I want is `z(x)` and `(x,y)` vertices. Does anyone know how to do something like this?

And actually I don't need the collection thing, I just want to plot one big square in an arbitrary direction.

I tried to simply enter the coordinates and use `ax.plot()`:

```
verts = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,1], [1,0,1], [0,0,0]])
ax.plot(verts[:,0], verts[:,1], verts[:,2], zdir='y')
```

and it indeed plots a square, but I can't (or don't know how to) fill the face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted! 
[image: this]

My rectangle will go from 0 to 10. So MAX=10.
What I did at first is try to define an axis between z and x. 
z=MAX-x was my choice.

And then I preceded to draw this axis for every small increment of x, thus creating the rectangle.
This is the code:

```
anArray = []    
for i in range(0, 101, 1):
    z = float(i)/10        
    #print "x: ", x
    y = 10 - z
    #print "y: ", y      
    for a in range(0, 101, 1):          
        anArray.append([float(a)/10, y, z])
    #endfor                    
#endfor
verts = np.array(anArray)
ax.plot(verts[:,0],verts[:,1],verts[:,2], zdir='y')
```